# How to retrieve array element from a specific position in CosmosDB document?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Suppose I have a document with the following structure,

```
{
    "VehicleDetailId": 1,
    "VehicleDetail": [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "Make": "BMW"
        },
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "Model": "ABDS"
        },
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "Trim": "5.6L/ASMD"
        },
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "Year": 2008
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to retrieve an array element located at a **specific position** from *VehicleDetail* array like I want to retrieve the second element, i.e.,

```
{
    "Id": 1,
    "Model": "ABDS"
}
```

or the third,

```
{
    "Id": 1,
    "Trim": "5.6L/ASMD"
}
```

How should I write the query to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built-in [ARRAY_SLICE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-array-slice) function.  This allows you to select part of an array.

Pass the array, starting position, number of elements to select.

```
SELECT ARRAY_SLICE(c.VehicleDetail, 1, 1) As SecondElement
FROM c
```

Output:

```
{
    "SecondElement": [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "Model": "ABDS"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Suppose I only want the id field from this result, how can we modify the query

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by others, ARRAY_SLICE can be used. If you want to select specific element in array, we can combine ARRAY_SLICE and ARRAY functions

```
SELECT ARRAY_SLICE((ARRAY(SELECT a.Id FROM a IN c.VehicleDetail)), 1, 1) as SecondElement FROM c
```